# Error converting drive info to a string array

Tags: c#, .net, properties, console-application

I have edited the question as the previous one was a vague and it didn't really get me anywhere so here's the edit:

Although I changed it to Count; instead of Count(); it was pretty much completely broken and all a mess to be honest so I decided to scrap the array and rewrite it:

```
public static void getdrives()
    {
        foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please insert USB drive...");
            // Here it would await insertion
            Console.WriteLine(d + " Drive Detected. Proceed with this drive? (press enter to continue, any other key to cancel.)");
            Console.Out.Flush();
            if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Are you sure? this will erase all the data on the drive. (press enter to continue, any other key to cancel.)");
                if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    //do something
                }
                else
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Count` is a property, not a method. It should be `dlist.Count` instead of `dlist.Count()`. Or better yet, don't use an ArrayList to begin with; it's been obsolete for years. Use a [generic list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) instead.

Comment: BTW, from MSDN: "We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development."

Answer (score 2):

The `Count` is a property not a method so you have to use `dlist.Count`. See the declaration of `Count` in `ArrayList` class.

```
// Summary:
//     Gets the number of elements actually contained in the System.Collections.ArrayList.
//
// Returns:
//     The number of elements actually contained in the System.Collections.ArrayList.

public virtual int Count { get; }
```